# Does Apache Hama like Hadoop Mapreduce has a monitoring webpage?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, monitoring, hama

Hadoop mapreduce's job tracker has a monitoring webpage at its port 50030, but when I tried to open a browser with my Hama BSPMaster node on its service port (which I set to 40000), it seems that Hama does not have such monitoring page.  The website of Hama seems not mention such type of monitoring tool.

Can I know whether the BSPMaster of Hama has such a monitoring page?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The web console runs at 40013, mentioned [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hama/GettingStarted).

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Originally I thought it was tied to the service port I set in the hama-site.xml.

Comment: I would be interested in the use case around BSP/Hama. Take a look at [Apache Tez](http://tez.incubator.apache.org/), note that it is still in the incubator.

Comment: I plan to use hama to process large graph.  Operations like finding connected components requires different nodes to share their progress.  Nodes in MapReduce framework typically can't communicate directly.  As a result, propagating updates from each Reducer requires multiple Map and Reduce passes, which introduces many unnecessary I/Os.  I don't know much about Tez.  Can I know what are the main applications for Apache Tez?

Comment: Also, take a look @ Apache Giraph.